# C# SQL Bulk Copy: Column returning "null" halfway

Tags: c#, excel, import, null, sqlbulkcopy

When I am using SQL Bulk Copy, my columns return "null" halfway through the insert...

The only thing I can think of is because of special characters such as "`/`" and "`-`". Is it at all possible to escape chars in SQL bulk Copy?

I've tried looking it up, but no one seems to have to escape chars in SQL, any other solutions?

**Entries from the excel sheet:**(Removed all formulas prior to export)

[image]

**After import to the database:**
(All Fields are VarChar(50))

[image: From the DataBase]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into my excel sheet a little more, I realized that my fields were set to "General" and **NOT** as "Text".

Go to `Home > Number > Select Dropdown to "Text"` Problem Fixed.